# Redis job queue (redis-smq): consumers in different containers, will they be handled multiple times?

Tags: node.js, redis, job-queue

I use the nodeJS lib redis-smq to manage a job queue via Redis.
Given I have the following infrastructure:

- 1 nodeJS container as job producer
- 10 nodeJS container as job consumer
- 1 Redis container as database

When the job producer now creates a job, is it guaranteed that the job is handled just by one of the consumers, if they all use the same job queue name and of course the same Redis instance? Or will several containers handle the same job at the same time?